# How do I make Active Job retry all jobs forever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activejob

I don't want active job to drop jobs when they fail. I want to have a chance to fix the failure and then let them re-run. I tried doing this:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on Exception, attempts: Float::INFINITY
end
```

but it didn't work. An email job failed and was just discarded. I'm using delayed_job as the implementation.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Looks like it should work: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5f94ea0812c1eb2b101e68e1c376f67f613417a6/activejob/lib/active_job/exceptions.rb#L59 Did you get any error?

Comment: What adapter do you use?

Comment: @HubertJakubiak: I had SMTP badly configured and jobs would be dropped after one attempt.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak: I'm using delayed job.

Comment: "An email job failed"


The issue may be that email jobs don't use ApplicationJob, so your code there didn't effect them. Your code may have worked otherwise, just not for email jobs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Delayed::Job, you end up with two retrying mechanisms on top of each other. Active Job, the Rails general implementation, and the Delayed::Job.

For Active::Job you can do:

```rb
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on Exception, wait: :exponentially_longer, attempts: Float::INFINITY
end
```

Without the `wait: :exponentially_longer`, you may end up with a lot of jobs trying every 3 seconds.

The behavior of this retrying method can be a bit odd if you are using Delayed::Job. The job runs and seems to succeed but since it fails, ActiveJob creates a new one to run at a later time. Because of that the field `attempts` in Delayed::Job remains at 0 and you need to look at the field `handler` to see how many times it was run.

One ActiveJob fails for the last time, the exception bubbles up to Delayed::Job which has its own retrying mechanism. Delayed::Job by default [retries 25 times and then deletes the job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details).

To make Delayed Job keep on trying forever, you can create an initialization file `config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb` changing the `max_attempts` values:

```rb
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = Float::INFINITY
```

If you are worried about losing jobs though, the jobs can fail and not be removed by setting:

```rb
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

which of the two you use, or how you mix them is up to you. Using Delayed::Job's makes the database make a bit more sense, using ActiveJob's means the method can be transported to other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

### retry_on exception, attempts: :unlimited (Rails 7.0+)

Starting from Rails 7.0, `ActiveJob` supports an ability to pass `attempts: :unlimited` to [`retry_on`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on) method:

> `:attempts` - Re-enqueues the job the specified number of times (default: 5 attempts) or a symbol reference of `:unlimited` to retry the job until it succeeds

For example:

```rb
class RemoteServiceJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # ...
  retry_on CustomInfrastructureException, wait: 5.minutes, attempts: :unlimited

  def perform(*args)
    # ...
  end
end
```

**Sources:**

- [ActiveJob::Exceptions::ClassMethods#retry_on](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on).
- [retry_on parameter attempts now accepts :unlimited](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41761).
- [What's New in Rails 7](https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/12/15/whats-new-in-rails7.html).

Answer (score 0):

We can implement own retry logic with passing `block` to `retry_on` following [retry_on Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on)

> may have its own retry mechanism or place it in a holding queue for inspection.

> You can also pass a block that'll be invoked if the retry attempts fail for custom logic rather than letting the exception bubble up. This block is yielded with the job instance as the first and the error instance as the second parameter.

```
retry_on Exception do |job, error|
  MyJob.perform_later(job)
end
```

Working example of infinite retry:

```
# test_job.rb

require 'active_record'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_job'
require 'globalid'

ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :async
GlobalID.app = 'app'
logger = ActiveJob::Base.logger

class ProcessPhotoJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |job, error|
    logger.info " retrying job #{job}"
    ProcessPhotoJob.perform_later(job)
  end

  def perform
    logger.info ' performing, but getting error:'
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
end

ProcessPhotoJob.perform_later

while true
  sleep 1
end
```

Which can be run with:

```
ruby test_job.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

retry_on Exception, wait: 5.minutes, attempts: :unlimited

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html